# Coder Manual, Stripe raises an error: This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I've checked every file that can contain the problem, tried to use an other API version so basically tried everything that I found on the internet.

Here is my User.rb file:

```js
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :plan
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token


  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the RegistrationsController:

```html
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :select_plan, only: :new

  def create
    super do |resource|
      if params[:plan]
        resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
        if resource.plan_id == 2
          resource.save_with_payment
        else
          resource.save
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def select_plan
    unless params[:plan] && (params[:plan] == '1' || params[:plan] == '2')
    redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

And last, the User.js file:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe_key"]').attr('content'));
  $("#from-submit-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
    var error = false;
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();

    if (!error) {
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
  });

  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    var f = $("#new_user");

    var token = response.id;

    f.append('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]" value="' + token + '" />');

    f.get(0).submit();
  }
});
```

I am getting frustrated, that I cant really find the problem though I tried several ways to solve it. Would apriciate anybody's help!!!

Comment: What version of the `stripe` gem do you use?

Comment: 1.16.1 is the version of the gem. The APIs i tried was the latest one and the 2015-01-11.

Comment: `1.16.1` is quite old, older than both api versions you tried. Did you consider updating to a newer version? At the moment `1.38.0` is the most recent version.

Comment: I've tried it and still getting the error "This customer has no attached payment source". Though I see 500 Internal Server after the server is trying to commit the transaction.

Comment: Stripe log gives 400 request error.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the customer is created without a token. In your code:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
```

`stripe_card_token` is probably `nil` or an empty string.

Note that in your JavaScript code, in the `stripeResponseHandler` callback, you should first check `response.error` to make sure that the token creation succeeded. You can find an example here: https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form#step-3-sending-the-form-to-your-server.

Answer (score 0):

I got my app working by adding

> .card

method to the Stripe createToken function in the User.js file.

> ```
>   if (!error) {
>       Stripe.card.createToken({
>         number: ccNum,
>         cvc: cvcNum,
>         exp_month: expMonth,
>         exp_year: expYear
>       }, stripeResponseHandler);
>     }
> ```